# Change bios splash screen

Tags: bios

I have a new HP 246 G1 notebook PC from the tamil nadu govt. The bios splash screen is a photo of the state chief minister.

I used 'universal bios backup toolkit 2.0' to take a backup of my present bios and loaded it in 'ezh20_2.1.0.4.exe' inside the bios editor. But the splash screen to be replaced is not showing there when I load the bios backup file.

I tried updating my bios to the latest version inside F.04.

I tried to enable 'fast boot' but that option is not available in this version of bios.

How can I disable or change the splash screen to the official HP splash screen?

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a utility called [EREPLOGO](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4095873&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D0%257CswItem%253Dob_108095_1%257CswEnvOID%253D4053%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D3%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) but it doesn't show up as a download for your system. On older HP models you could put an image in the HP_Tools partition as follows:

Adding a custom logo to the HP_Tools partition

Instead of using one of the EREPLOGO utilities to replace the default HP logo, you can also place your custom image in a specific location in the HP_Tools partition.

1. Select the custom logo image you want to use. For BIOS 09, BIOS 2011, and BIOS 2012, it must be in .jpg file format. For BIOS 08 it must be in .bmp file format.
2. In the Hewlett-Packard folder on the HP_TOOLS partition, create a folder called “Logo.”
3. Save the image in the \Hewlett-Packard\Logo folder.
4. Rename the image as HPlogo.jpg (or HPlogo.bmp for BIOS 08 systems).
5. Reboot the computer, and then press the f10 key at POST to enter the BIOS Setup.
6. Select System Configuration, and then select Boot Options.
7. Select Custom Logo, and then select Enabled.
8. For BIOS 2011 and BIOS 2012 generations, clear the checkbox for FastBoot.
9. Save the changes and exit Setup.
   The custom logo will now display during POST.

You can check if there is anything there.

Source: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03394575.pdf